# Install bcrypt on AWS Elastic Beanstalk failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, bcrypt, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Look like installation of the bcrypt failed since I can see in the log message `Cannot find module 'bcrypt'`, that is mean it was not installed.
I was add `.npmrc` file with `unsafe-perm=true` and add `00_change_npm_permissions.config` with the following content:

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/00_set_tmp_permissions.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      chown -R nodejs:nodejs /tmp/.npm
```

But none of the solutions are working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix it by modifying a little bit `scripts` in package.json this way:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "dev": "ts-node ./src/server.ts",
    "bcrypt": "npm install bcrypt",
    "start": "npm run bcrypt && node server.js",
    "prod": "npm run build && npm run start"
  },
```

Comment: should I remove bcrypt from dependencies ?

Comment: I suppose so, it will be added automatically if corresponding npm command will run